# Beautiful Soup and extracting a string part of an array

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Considering this URL:
http://www.nyse.com/about/listed/chn.html

I am trying to retrieve this string : 'Pacific Ex Japan Funds' however it is not in the soup !?!

```
fundCode = 'chn'
url = 'http://www.nyse.com/about/listed/' + fundCode + '.html'
html = urllib2.urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
```

Which is weird as other parts of the table are in the soup.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you download the HTML (without a browser)

```
content = html.read()
```

you'll see the page data is provided by JavaScript functions.

To extract information from this page, you'll need a library that can process JavaScript.

One way to do that is to use [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/), another way is to use [PyQt's WebKit](http://webscraping.com/blog/Scraping-JavaScript-webpages-with-webkit/).